# How to calculate the minimum translation vector between a circle and a rectangle?

Tags: pygame, collision-detection, collision

I am aware of how to detect collision with circle and rectangles but I am not sure how to find the minimum translation vector between the two. I know how to do it with the SAT collision detection algorithm, but that is too complicated for my simple implementation right now.

I am really not sure what to do except change the x-coordinate appropriately.

Here is the code. When you pressed the down button, what I would want is that the circle automatically is "shoved" to the left (since it is already positioned a bit left to the center) when constantly having the down button pressed i.e. it is moving down but sliding to the left.

```
import pygame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    display.fill((255, 255, 255))
    circle_x = 240
    circle_y = 50
    pygame.draw.circle(display, (0, 0, 255), (circle_x, circle_y), 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 255), (240, 250, 20, 250))
    pygame.display.update()    
    vel = 1
    is_down_held = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            circle_y += vel

        display.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.draw.circle(display, (0, 0, 255), (circle_x, circle_y), 50)
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 255), (240, 250, 20, 250))
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        dt = clock.tick(60)
        dt /= 1000
```

I tried moving the x-coordinate with some constant, however, it looks unrealistic and is actually passing through the rectangle sometimes (since it actually doesn't detect the rectangle).

Comment: What do you mean by *"the minimum translation vector"* Do you mean the shortest distance between the circle and the rectangle?

Comment: In this example, the center point of the circle is above the top of the rectangle. If the circle "falls down", then the most bottom point of the circle hits the rectangle. So an ideal circle in an ideal world won't be "shoved" to the left. To achieve this, the center point of the circle has to be a bit left from the left of rectangle.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sorry yeah, I meant to put the circle with `x` coordinate as 240.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Like in the SAT collision detection, the MTV is the shortest distance between the two objects which will separate them. So that is what I mean by that.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might want to take a look at leveraging a physics engine if you simulation gets more complicated, e.g. `pymunk` (which is a wrapper to the C chipmunk 2D physics library), especially if you are concerned with "realism."

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Okay, thanks. I was just hoping for a simple algorithm since I thought it wasn't too complicated and I just needed to be steered in the right direction. It is a simple 2D game with one object and one rigid body but I will look into `pymunk`.

Comment: I will definitely take a look and read up on SAT in the meantime out of curiosity to see if I can get a more helpful answer for you, just wanted to point out that library if you were looking for a pre-built solution.

Comment: [This](https://jcharry.com/blog/physengine10) seems like a pretty decent starting point for code for SAT (with the last part being useful for your case).

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Thanks for that. I implemented SAT before (in Java) between two convex polygons but not with circles (since there are infinite axes for it). If you see this: http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/ under 'Curved Shapes' it says it can get pretty complicated for a circle. However, I don't really need full SAT detection, just in one axis (since my objects are always going down and not rotating). Hopefully, there is a simpler solution or else I would have to resort to that.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Hm, thanks a lot for this. I believe I read this when I was implementing SAT but never read up on the Circle vs Polygon part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems like I had to implement SAT collision detection at the end anyways. To calculate the minimum translation vector between a rectangle and a circle, you go through the necessary axes for the shapes (see https://jcharry.com/blog/physengine10 and https://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/sat/ for an explanation on that) then you take the smallest overlap axis for when there is a collision. Below is the code using pygame GUI library:

```
import math
import pygame


class Vector:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.magnitude = math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
        if self.magnitude != 0:
            self.direction_x = -x / self.magnitude
            self.direction_y = -y / self.magnitude
        else:
            self.direction_x = 0
            self.direction_y = 0

    def normalize(self):
        if self.magnitude != 0:
            self.x /= self.magnitude
            self.y /= self.magnitude
            self.magnitude = 1


def project_vector(vector1, vector2):
    return get_dot_product(vector1, get_unit_vector(vector2))


def get_dot_product(vector1, vector2):
    return (vector1.x * vector2.x) + (vector1.y * vector2.y)


def get_normal(vector):
    return Vector(vector.y, -vector.x)


def get_vector(point):
    return Vector(point[0], point[1])


def scale_vector(vector, magnitude):
    return Vector(vector.x*magnitude, vector.y*magnitude)


def get_unit_vector(vector):
    if vector.magnitude != 0:
        return scale_vector(vector, 1 / vector.magnitude)
    else:
        return scale_vector(vector, 0)


def get_closest_point(circle_centre, rectangle_points):
    closest_distance = float('inf')
    closest_point = None
    for point in rectangle_points:
        distance = (circle_centre[0] - point[0])**2 + (circle_centre[1] - point[1])**2
        if distance <= closest_distance:
            closest_distance = distance
            closest_point = point
    return closest_point


def is_collision(circle_centre, rectangle_points):
    closest_point = get_closest_point(circle_centre, rectangle_points)
    rectangle_edge_vectors = []
    for point in rectangle_points:
        rectangle_edge_vectors += [get_vector(point)]
    rectangle_edge_normals = []
    for i in range(len(rectangle_points) - 1):
        rectangle_edge_normals += [get_normal(get_vector((rectangle_points[i + 1][0] - rectangle_points[i][0], rectangle_points[i + 1][1] - rectangle_points[i][1])))]
    rectangle_edge_normals += [get_normal(get_vector((rectangle_points[0][0] - rectangle_points[len(rectangle_points) - 1][0], rectangle_points[0][1] - rectangle_points[len(rectangle_points) - 1][1])))]
    rectangle_edge_normals += [get_vector((circle_centre[0] - closest_point[0], circle_centre[1] - closest_point[1]))]
    axes = rectangle_edge_normals
    vectors = rectangle_edge_vectors
    for axis in axes:
        current_rect_max_x = float('-inf')
        current_rect_min_x = float('inf')
        for vector in vectors:
            current_rect_projection = project_vector(vector, axis)
            if current_rect_projection >= current_rect_max_x:
                current_rect_max_x = current_rect_projection
            if current_rect_projection <= current_rect_min_x:
                current_rect_min_x = current_rect_projection
        current_circle_projection = project_vector(get_vector(circle_centre), axis)
        current_circle_max_x = current_circle_projection + 25
        current_circle_min_x = current_circle_projection - 25
        if current_rect_min_x > current_circle_max_x or current_circle_min_x > current_rect_max_x:
            return False
    return True


def get_minimum_translation_vector(circle_centre, rectangle_points):
    closest_point = get_closest_point(circle_centre, rectangle_points)
    rectangle_edge_vectors = []
    for point in rectangle_points:
        rectangle_edge_vectors += [get_vector(point)]
    rectangle_edge_normals = []
    for i in range(len(rectangle_points) - 1):
        rectangle_edge_normals += [get_normal(get_vector((rectangle_points[i + 1][0] - rectangle_points[i][0], rectangle_points[i + 1][1] - rectangle_points[i][1])))]
    rectangle_edge_normals += [get_normal(get_vector((rectangle_points[0][0] - rectangle_points[len(rectangle_points) - 1][0], rectangle_points[0][1] - rectangle_points[len(rectangle_points) - 1][1])))]
    rectangle_edge_normals += [get_vector((circle_centre[0] - closest_point[0], circle_centre[1] - closest_point[1]))]
    axes = rectangle_edge_normals
    for axis in axes:
        axis.normalize()
    vectors = rectangle_edge_vectors
    minimum_translation_vector = Vector(axes[0].x, axes[0].y)
    minimum_translation_vector.magnitude = float('inf')
    current_minimum_translation_vector = Vector(axes[0].x, axes[0].y)
    current_minimum_translation_vector.magnitude = float('inf')
    for axis in axes:
        current_rect_max_x = float('-inf')
        current_rect_min_x = float('inf')
        for vector in vectors:
            current_rect_projection = project_vector(vector, axis)
            if current_rect_projection >= current_rect_max_x:
                current_rect_max_x = current_rect_projection
            if current_rect_projection <= current_rect_min_x:
                current_rect_min_x = current_rect_projection
        current_circle_projection = project_vector(get_vector(circle_centre), axis)
        current_circle_max_x = current_circle_projection + 25
        current_circle_min_x = current_circle_projection - 25
        current_minimum_translation_vector = axis
        current_minimum_translation_vector.magnitude = abs(current_circle_min_x - current_rect_max_x)
        if current_minimum_translation_vector.magnitude <= minimum_translation_vector.magnitude:
            minimum_translation_vector = axis
            minimum_translation_vector.magnitude = current_minimum_translation_vector.magnitude
    return minimum_translation_vector


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    rectangle_points_main = [(250, 250), (300, 250), (300, 300), (250, 300)]
    circle_centre_main = (0, 0)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            circle_centre_main = (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1])
        display.fill((255, 255, 255))
        if is_collision(circle_centre_main, rectangle_points_main):
            pygame.draw.circle(display, (255, 0, 0), circle_centre_main, 25)
            minimum_translation_vector_main = get_minimum_translation_vector(circle_centre_main, rectangle_points_main)
            dx = minimum_translation_vector_main.magnitude * minimum_translation_vector_main.direction_x
            dy = minimum_translation_vector_main.magnitude * minimum_translation_vector_main.direction_y
            rectangle_points_main = [(rectangle_points_main[0][0] + dx, rectangle_points_main[0][1] + dy),
                                     (rectangle_points_main[1][0] + dx, rectangle_points_main[1][1] + dy),
                                     (rectangle_points_main[2][0] + dx, rectangle_points_main[2][1] + dy),
                                     (rectangle_points_main[3][0] + dx, rectangle_points_main[3][1] + dy)]
        else:
            pygame.draw.circle(display, (0, 0, 255), circle_centre_main, 25)
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 0), (rectangle_points_main[0][0], rectangle_points_main[0][1], 50, 50))
        dt = clock.tick(60)
        dt /= 1000
        pygame.display.update()
```